# Protractor wait for async requests

Tags: async-await, protractor

I am working on an application where the data is saved asynchronously while it is being edited. As soon as a specific action is performed, protractor quits the test which leads to unsaved data. How to make protractor wait till all the requests are finished?

Comment: you need to provide more details. attach the script that saves the data asynchronously, mention where you call it (from spec or config)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66072132/6793637

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66072132/6793637

You can read this answer on how to use protractor

you can use await with any promise , but for call back function you have to make it a promise as you cannot use await with callback functions

Example:

```
const readFilePromise = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, options, (err, data) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      resolve(data)
    })
  })
}
```

so we created a file read promise that resolves only after the call back is resolved

Now you can await it as

```
await readFilePromise ()
```