# Should I await expect(<async>) conditions

Tags: protractor

https://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await shows an example of using async/ await in protractor, but includes the line:

```
    expect(await greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
```

But I don't understand how that can be correct: if the greeting.getText() is async (indicated by the await), then the text won't be known until after that line has completed.  Isn't:

```
    await expect(await greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
```

So we definitely wait for the text to be obtained (and checked) before we move on. In this example, it's not too important (assuming the expect check does execute), but in general, is there any risk of re-ordering the getText() with further operations (which may remove it from the DOM, for example).

Is it in practice safe if it's only browser-based async operations, as they execute serially anyway (so the getText() will complete before a subsequent operation?

Presumably if we included non-browser based async operations (e.g. we did a http request to a server), then the ordering wouldn't be guaranteed, so best practice would be to write 'await expect(...).toX(...)'  (which is safe even if the expect expression is not async).

Of course, with all that, we end up with 'await' on the beginning of nearly every line, which looks a bit ugly.

Answer (score 1):

`expect(await greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');`

is the correct way to go.

`await` stops execution queue and waits until first command is done before moving on to the second one, IN ORDER TO RESOLVE PROMISE. So if your function is synchronous and doesn't return a promise, why `await` it?

From protractor page, [.getText()](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) returns `!webdriver.promise.Promise.<string>` - long story short, it returns you a promise, thus it needs to be resolved

`expect(await greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');` on the other hand returns `undefined` (try to console.log it). And since it doesn't return promise, and there is nothing to resolve, `await` is not needed

Additional example

Lets assume you want a synchronous function to take parameters:

```
someFunction("2" === "1", 1, await $welcomeMessage.getText());
```

First thing js does, is it runs each argument of the function as a separarte statement. i.e.

```
"2" === "1" // false
1 // 1
await $welcomeMessage.getText() // 'welcome user'
```

So by the time when function will be ready to be executed the overall statement will look like so

```
someFunction(false, 1, 'welcome user');
```

In other words, even though it looks like the function takes asynchronous promise which you need to wait for, in fact, this promise is resolved before it's executed. So if `someFunction` itself is synchronous, it doesn't need to be awaited

Comment: hope that doesn't confuse you even more :)

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is really simple after the introduction of await, don't need to complicate it

First disable selenium control flow in config file, just add this line in config file:

```
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false
```

https://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow

Now in test use:

```
  it('should find an element by text input model', async function() {
    await browser.get('app/index.html#/form');

    var username =element(by.model('username'));
    await username.clear();
    await username.sendKeys('Jane Doe');

    var name = element(by.binding('username'));

    expect(await name.getText()).toEqual('Jane Doe');

  });
```

Note that i am not using await for

```
 var name = element(by.binding('username'));
```

This is because in protractor the find element action is not triggered unless you call a method on it

so you don't have to use await there

you won't get element not found unless you call any method on it .