# Angular E2E Testing Script Timeout

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm new to Angular
I created a project with it which is working fine so far. But now I want to add some testing to it.

Unfortunately I'm not able to make it work.

So my app is a basic todo app.

In the test I want to check if task was created.

**This is my task-form.po.ts**

```
import { by, element, ElementArrayFinder, ElementFinder } from 'protractor';

export class TaskForm {

  get taskCreateButton(): ElementFinder {
    return element(by.css('#task-create-btn'));
  }

  get taskListItems(): ElementArrayFinder {
    return element.all(by.css('mat-list-item'));
  }

  get taskForm(): ElementFinder {
    return element(by.id('task-form'));
  }

  get taskFormInput(): ElementFinder {
    return element(by.id('mat-input-0'));
  }
}
```

**app.e2e-spec.ts**

```
...

describe('TaskForm', () => {
  let taskForm: TaskForm;
  let startCount: number;
  let createBtn: ElementFinder;
  let taskListItems: ElementArrayFinder;
  let taskFormNewInput: ElementFinder;
  let newTaskItemsNum: number;


  beforeEach( () => {
    taskForm = new TaskForm();
    createBtn = taskForm.taskCreateButton;
    taskListItems = taskForm.taskListItems;
    taskFormNewInput = taskForm.taskFormInput;
    taskListItems.count().then((originalCount: number) => {
      startCount = originalCount;
    });
  });

  it('should enter test task to task form', async () => {
    await taskFormNewInput.clear().then(() => {
      taskFormNewInput.sendKeys('This is a test task');
    });

    taskFormNewInput.getAttribute('value').then(taskInput => {
      expect(taskInput).toEqual('This is a test task');
    });
  });

  it('should add a task', async () => {
    await taskFormNewInput.clear().then(() => {
      taskFormNewInput.sendKeys('This is a test task');
    });

    await createBtn.click();
    newTaskItemsNum = await taskForm.taskListItems.count();
    expect(newTaskItemsNum).toBe(startCount);
  });
});
```

The task will be added but then it's running in a script timeout.

I tried several things but either the task will not be created or it's running in a script timeout.

Comment: don't mix `.then()` and `await`

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66072132/6793637

Read the above stack overflow to know how to use protractor-jasmine ( javascript not type script)

But the approach and design remains the same .

When using Type script use : use ES2017 as await was introduced in this version

https://blog.logrocket.com/async-await-in-typescript/

Also some of the good practices:

1. Split test cases to smaller use cases if the spec (It block) is taking longer Jasmine.Default_timeout
2. If you indeed need more time then set that in config file or per spec :

To set from config:

```
https://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts
```

for all script time out increase config.allScriptsTimeout:

```
 allScriptsTimeout: timeout_in_millis
```

for Default time out error use it in config.jasmine.Opts

```
  jasmineNodeOpts: {defaultTimeoutInterval: timeout_in_millis}
```