# Instead of using the explicit wait multiple times, do we have any alertnate ways

Tags: reactjs, protractor

Earlier i used to automate angluarjs application using protarctor. Now i wanted to automate react js application using protarctor.So, without using implicit wait, my Test Scripts are getting failed.

My code:

```
var Login = require('../pageObject/Login.po');
var Decks = require('../pageObject/Decks.po');
var LoginPD = require('../pageData/login.pd.json');
var errorMessagesPD = require('../pageData/errorMessages.pd.json');
var decksPD = require('../pageData/decks.pd.json');
describe('Login', function () {
  var loginPO = new Login();
  var decksPO = new Decks();
  beforeAll(function () {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    loginPO.getUrl();
});
    it('Validate that Decks label is displayed in the Decks & Cards module', function() {
    loginPO.enterUsername(LoginPD.Adminusername);
    loginPO.enterPassword(LoginPD.Adminpassword);
    loginPO.logInBtn.click();
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(decksPO.decksLabel), 5000);
    expect(decksPO.decksLabel.getText()).toBe(decksPD.deckslabel);
  });
  it('Validate that Add(+) icon is displayed in the Decks & Cards module', function() {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(decksPO.addIcon), 5000);
    expect(decksPO.addIcon.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
  });
  it('Validate that "Create a Deck" popup is displayed after clicking on the Add(+) icon', function() {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(decksPO.addIcon), 5000);
    decksPO.addIcon.click();
    expect(decksPO.createDeckPopup.getText()).toEqual(decksPD.CreateDeckPopuplabel);
  });
  it('Validate that "Please enter the valid deck name and description." message is displayed when no data is entered in username and password fields' , function() {
    decksPO.createDeck.click();
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(decksPO.deckwithnodatamessage), 5000);
    decksPO.deckwithnodatamessage.getText().then(function(message){
    expect(message).toEqual(errorMessagesPD.deckwithnodata);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thats not implict wait , thats explicit wait . For non angular pages protractor works like normal webdriverjs , so you need the explicit wait like in your question

Comment: modified the question, i think adding explicit wait multiple times is not the correct way, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Adding explict wait inside test is not a good practice if it needs to be repeated many times .

A better approach would be to add the wait inside the page object model.

There are many issues with your code :

1. Dependency between tests
2. Not using explict wait inside page opbject method
3. Not using await ,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66072132/6793637